# Deprecated create_function() call

Tags: php, php-7.2

I just updated my server to the latest version of php 7.2 and now I have some  depreciation warnings. What should I do?

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Here is my code:

```
if(!array_key_exists('callable', $this->translation_plural)) {
    $this->translation_plural['callable'] = create_function('$n', $this->translation_plural['function']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://php.net/create_function) recommends using anonymous functions. Given that `$this->translation_plural['function']` looks like it is a string, you should consider a rewrite.

If you want to get rid of the warning, you can use the following:

```
$this->translation_plural['callable'] = function($n) { return eval($this->translation_plural['function']); };
```

This doesn't help your code at all, you are still using `eval()` which is bad practise. The documentation [warns against using it.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

The only difference is, `create_function()` used it internally, now it is very explicit.